# wp_mail only displays message. ignore other fields. (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, email

WP_Mail only shows message from the user and it does not show any data posted by the user. I mostly tried everything and been through 3/4 pages in Google for help before posting it here. I am also trying to display logged in information in the e-mail to the admin using $current_user function.

Here's the code I trying it to work:

```
$et_contact_error = true;
    } else if ( empty($_POST['et_contact_title']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_art']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_gen']) || empty($_POST['et_contact_message']) ){
        $et_error_message .= '<p>' . esc_html__('Make sure you fill all fields. ','Lucid') . '</p>';
        $et_contact_error = true;
    }


} else {
    $et_contact_error = true;
    if ( isset($_SESSION['et_first_digit'] ) ) unset( $_SESSION['et_first_digit'] );
    if ( isset($_SESSION['et_second_digit'] ) ) unset( $_SESSION['et_second_digit'] );
}

if ( !isset($_SESSION['et_first_digit'] ) ) $_SESSION['et_first_digit'] = $et_first_digit = rand(1, 15);
else $et_first_digit = $_SESSION['et_first_digit'];

if ( !isset($_SESSION['et_second_digit'] ) ) $_SESSION['et_second_digit'] = $et_second_digit = rand(1, 15);
else $et_second_digit = $_SESSION['et_second_digit'];

if ( ! $et_contact_error && isset( $_POST['_wpnonce-et-contact-form-submitted'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce-et-contact-form-submitted'], 'et-contact-form-submit' ) ) {
    $et_email_to = ( isset($et_ptemplate_settings['et_email_to']) && !empty($et_ptemplate_settings['et_email_to']) ) ? $et_ptemplate_settings['et_email_to'] : get_site_option('admin_email');

    $et_site_name = is_multisite() ? $current_site->site_name : get_bloginfo('name');

    $contact_name   = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['et_contact_name'] );
    $contact_email  = sanitize_email( $_POST['et_contact_email'] );

    $headers  = 'From: ' . $contact_name . ' <' . $contact_email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $contact_name . ' <' . $contact_email . '>';

    **wp_mail( apply_filters( 'et_contact_page_email_to', $et_email_to ), sprintf( '%s - ' . sanitize_text_field( $_POST['et_contact_title'] ), $et_site_name ), wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['et_contact_title'] ), apply_filters( 'et_contact_page_headers', $headers, $contact_name, $contact_email, $message ) );**

    $et_error_message = '<p class="contact_info">' . esc_html__('Thanks for contacting us, we will reply to your query within next 48 hours. ','Lucid') . '<a href="#">Back to Home Page</a>' . '</p>';
}
```

?>

I have tried adding all the fields in the wp_mail function but it didn't work.

```
wp_mail( apply_filters( 'et_contact_page_email_to', $et_email_to ), sprintf( '%s - ' . sanitize_text_field( $_POST['et_contact_title'] ), $et_site_name ), wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['et_contact_title, et_contact_art, et_contact_gen, et_contact_message'] ), apply_filters( 'et_contact_page_headers', $headers, $contact_name, $contact_email ) );
```

if possible to get all the fields information in e-mail to admin using wp_mail using $current_user. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorted the issue.. there were loads of error in the file. Getting the e-mails now of current user with all the fields information. <br/><br/>1 small error message "unexpected ','" in this line. $message .= sprintf(__('Title: %s'), wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['et_contact_title'] ) . "\r\n"; tried but it keeps giving me same error. M i missing something? thanks :)

Comment: sorted that too lol..